# Can `ValidateUnsigned` be used outside the runtime?

Tags: unsigned, beefy

I see this comment while reading through the beefy pallet
[Beefy equivocation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2bb370fbc36b2631dd85e6f1c1952cdfe7b8db8c/frame/beefy/src/equivocation.rs#L32-L35)

Comment: please give more context to your question, it's not easy to understand as it is